# Magento2 custom form issue

Tags: magento2, forms

I am facing an issue in Magento 2.2.3 it's working fine in local.

Please find the issue below:

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid XML in file 
>   app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customform_submission_saveform_listing.xml:

Element 'argument': This element is not expected.

I am unable to solve this issue.

Please find the code below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <!-- ... other block of code -->
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters" />
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customform_submission/saveform/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Record</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customform_submission_saveform_listing.customform_submission_saveform_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">customform_submission_saveform_listing.customform_submission_saveform_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">spinner_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Record</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="nameOfDataSource">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">customform_submission_saveform_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">level_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">level_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">level_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="spinner_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="level_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">level_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="level_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">First Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Last Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Customform\Submission\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PostActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">level_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share xml file?

Comment: hi @levinsky please find the updated question

Comment: I can't see code from this file in your answer

Comment: Not in answer check it in question

Comment: sorry now check the update question

Comment: you didi not complete `listing` tag at the end of file like this `</listing>`.

Comment: sorry its missing in question in my code it is ok, now the result is same exception

Comment: Please share full error.

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid XML in file /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customform_submission_saveform_listing.xml:
Element 'argument': This element is not expected.
Line: 37


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid XML in file /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customform_submission_saveform_listing.xml:
Element 'argument': This element is not expected.
Line: 37

Comment: Hi please find the error

Comment: Hi @kunj i have updated the question with error image please find the image.

Comment: I would suggest you, to compare your XML file with any default module's UI component XML file, then you can find the differences and correct those. I can see a lot of differences.

Comment: Try this : `<settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>` instead of `<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customform_submission_saveform_listing.customform_submission_saveform_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="add">
                <url path="*/*/new"/>
                <class>primary</class>
                <label translate="true">Add New Record</label>
            </button>
        </buttons>
        <spinner>spinner_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>customform_submission_saveform_listing.customform_submission_saveform_listing_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="nameOfDataSource">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">customform_submission_saveform_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">level_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">level_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">level_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <!-- ... other block of code -->
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters" />
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="delete">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Delete Record</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="customform_submission/saveform/massDelete"/>
                    <type>delete</type>
                    <label translate="true">Delete</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="spinner_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="level_id">
            <settings>
                <indexField>level_id</indexField>
                <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
                <resizeDefaultWidth>55</resizeDefaultWidth>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="level_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="name">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">First Name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="description">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Last Name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Customform\Submission\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PostActions">
            <settings>
                <indexField>level_id</indexField>
                <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
                <resizeDefaultWidth>107</resizeDefaultWidth>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Magento has changed code style. 
Flush cache and try again.

Comment: i have followed the above answer but the error is remain same:1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid XML in file /var/www/html/app/code/Customform/Submission/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customform_submission_saveform_listing.xml:
Element 'argument': This element is not expected.
Line: 35

Comment: update XML content on question.

Comment: Please find the updated code in question.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @kunj i have insterted your code , issue is remain

Comment: have you flushed cache?

Comment: yes flushed the cache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78724/discussion-between-kunj-and-shivashankar-m).

Comment: I have recreate your XML please check this.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kunj its worked for me thanks for your patience for my errors solve.

Comment: Welcome, I can understand, happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example of the UI Component created module if you will look into this then you may find the solution.

Here is the link :- [Sample UI Component Module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-form-uicomponent)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
```

with

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's 2021 so I'm sure you've since resolved this issue and long forgotten about the pain caused by Magento layouts!

That said, I had an almost identical issue with a custom module's adminhtml grid.

Assuming the line it's referencing is the top of this one

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customform_submission_saveform_listing.customform_submission_saveform_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">customform_submission_saveform_listing.customform_submission_saveform_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">spinner_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Record</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

(After the closing tag `</listingToolbar>`)

I simply moved that entire block to the top of the file, directly after the opening `<listing xmlns` node.

Why this worked in default mode and not developer mode? I have no idea. But it seemed to work perfectly once I yeeted that upwards.

I hope this helps fellow individuals who have torn their hair out.